# $parse interceptorFn, expensiveChecks arguments

Tags: angularjs

I checked out the AngularJS source to see how event handlers are implemented and I saw that `$parse` service is called with additional arguments: `interceptorFn`, `expensiveChecks`. It is not documented in official documentation. I wonder why & what is the purpose of these arguments?

Comment: `expensiveChecks` flag there for , if any code detect any suspicious code in parse variable like `function`,`malicious` OR `DOM nodes` every-time it calls `ensureSafeObject` which tells to process with this parsing or just throw an error..but not sure who is going to pass that variable **OR**  how can we used it :(

Comment: These are used internally in Angular... `interceptorFn` allows you to "intercept" the value produced by a watched expression and return some function of that value to the watch handler.

Comment: @PankajParkar post an answer if you can

Comment: @jeremy I wish, I could, but I have not dig through it, to give a proper answer ;) :p